Can I Use A Server In International Waters To Provide Illegal Content Without Getting Arrested?
This is currently just a theoretical question.
If I took a ship to international waters, set up servers on it, and used it to host illegal content could I do that without getting in trouble?
"Illegal content" means movies, TV shows, anime, cartoons, game roms, ebooks, etc.. No porno. Strictly non-porno.
Could I do that without getting taken down like KimCartoon recently did?
Let me know.

"Without getting arrested" is a totally different question to "without getting taken down". If you go somewhere there are no police, then you cannot be arrested. But nobody would be obligated to provide you with an internet connection, and many nations have laws which would require them to stop providing you with services or otherwise block access to your content, if a valid takedown notice was issued by the copyright-holders.

It works both ways: "somewhere there are no police, then you cannot be arrested", but similarly there is nobody to protect you if unidentified parties turn up and smash your installation.

Before the internet pirate radio was often broadcast from the sea. There is also a "country" called Sealand on a disused oil platform, with their own laws.

I am no expert and have no ability to research this properly, but it occurs to me that a person would perhaps still be culpable for these actions if they occurred in international waters, but the person themself lived in a country where the actions were illegal

came here to post what Danny posted. OP: Read up on the history of Sealand.

A historical note (no idea if it's still true today): Before the Internet became widespread and piracy websites started popping up everywhere, the server (and the company, if it existed) was often hosted in Eastern Europe, because of the infamous slowness of the governments to comply with the Western countries' takedown requests, due to various reasons of history, ideology, internal corruption. (And a poor country sometimes doesn't want to give the impression of pushing foreign investors away).

Technical note: the question assumes that censorship resistance = no law, however the social media world is switching from centralized "platforms" to federated and decentralized networks of servers, hosted in multiple countries by independent people (grassroots), under the assumption that a redundant network is self-healing and works as a backup of itself. Mastodon is the famous example and made big news recently, but to stay on-topic with video hosting, I should rather say PeerTube + Sepia Search. But all this is about censorship, not piracy.

The best place to pull this stunt is currently the North Korean embassy in Moscow.

International waters means there's no law saying you can't do that, but there's also no law saying they can't arrest you for not breaking the not-law.

Not really.
Every ship needs to carry the flag of a country (the "flag state" of the ship), and this state defines the laws which are valid on a ship. So if you kill somebody on a ship flying the Swiss flag, you'll be prosecuted in Switzerland, even if that happens somewhere in the pacific ocean. Since copyright infringement is mostly a civil matter, somebody would need to file a lawsuit first.
In theory, there's the possibility for a ship to not fly a flag. That's however bad for a variety of reasons (mostly safety). Here's a question trying to answer what might happen if your ship has no flag. Notably, it does not prevent you from being boarded.
How they would start an investigation over there and whether they would have the workforce to really take you down (assuming you're using various international satelite services) is a different question. But as always: A crime that is hard to prevent doesn't make it less illegal.
Edit: Based on the comments, a thought about the possible revenue of trying this hypothetical.
You will need to refill your fuel and rations once in a while. For this you need to enter a port, where it gets difficult if you don't have a proper registration. So lets use another, properly registered, vessel to transport those to your "warez ship", but that second ship adds to your costs. And you will need quite a bit of fuel to run the generators that power the servers and routers you have on board. If you want to power them all from solar panels, you would need quite a big boat to have reasonable room, but I believe that would be doable. So lets calculate with two 50ft sailboats, properly equipped they're at roughly $1M each. Then you need crew - since it's illegal anyway disregard working regulations, but add hush money - $100k per year. Not including maintenance costs.
I seriously doubt your warez server, running on a slow satellite network and with rather low-power hardware, will provide you with enough revenue to pay all this. It will be much cheaper and easier to rent a server in some existing country with minimal prosecution for internet crimes.

In theory, there's the possibility for a ship to not fly a flag. — And since OP's question is about content piracy, why not double-dip...

@MindwinRememberMonica Maybe yes, but you might want to sail to a port every now and then to refill your rations and fuel. And that's where it gets really problematic if you don't have a flag. Of course you can sail to some state with corrupt border forces, but then they won't care if you're robbed either...

@PMF Heck, they might even do the robbin- I mean, levy certain administrative and support fees, surely you understand in these difficult and unsafe times, yes?

"if you kill somebody on a ship flying the Swiss flag, you'll be prosecuted in Switzerland, even if that happens somewhere in the pacific ocean": that assumes the ship was in international waters, right? If the crime occurred in country X, would it still be prosecuted in Switzerland or would countryX take precedence since the ship was in its waters? (feel free to tell me to go post a question if this is too much of a tangent).

@terdon I have asked myself this question before, and I never got a final answer, so it might be good to be posted as separate question. Switzerland's Seeschifffahrtsgesetz Art 4 is quite explicit when it comes to crimes, but not so clear when it's about civil lawsuits.

@PMF rations and fuel can always be ferried from another craft that does have a flag.  The only time you'd be forced to port is when you need repair.

@MarkRansom and only for certain repairs (those concerning hull integrity). Theoretically you could get by even without an engine or other means of propulsion – the lawless vessel stays anchored in international waters, and you have another (properly registered) one which you use to get to shore and back.

@user149408 See my thoughts above. This gets really hypothetical now. Oh, and "international waters" usually means more than 120 nautical miles off shore, and I'm not sure there are any places where you can anchor that far offshore. For a boat the size of a large yacht, the maximum water depth for anchoring is around 20m.

For example, according to German law, a crime happens in Germany and can be prosecuted in Germany if it has its effect in Germany.
So if what you do is illegal according to German law, and the illegal materials are sent to Germany, then they can prosecute you. Laying their hands on you might be difficult if you stay on high sea, but if you touch land there might be an extradition request waiting for you. Other countries have their own rules, but looking at where the crime happens, and not where the perpetrator and his tools are, wouldn't be unusual.
Some countries might not be prepared for this, because 50 years ago before the internet a crime perpetrated in X by a person in Y would have been so rare.

The German Navy can lay hands on them, but likely does not help enforce German law.

@JonCuster they would enforce german law and be in accordance with UNCLOS: the unregistred vessel is doing piracy, and that allows any country's forces to bring them up and to their own port for trial.

Sure, in theory they could, but it is highly unlikely they would do anything unless it became a big deal in high government levels. Armed forces don’t like playing cop.

@Trish Providing illegal content on the internet doesn't seem like "illegal acts of violence or detention, or any act of depredation" as per the definition of piracy in UNCLOS.

@JonCuster tell that to all the counternarcotics operations that US armed forces do in the Caribbean and Pacific

@Caleth - drug interdiction is a high profile government goal. Note that the US Coast Guard is the main entity doing it, not the US Navy. Shutting down one of a million sites providing content is not a high priority.

Even if you never touch land again and no country is willing to send the coast guard to collect you, they can still go after your assets and try to get you offline. As the satellite-internet providers you'd need are large companies, generally headquartered in developed countries, they would probably be quick to comply with any court order and any money intended to pay them would be seized once it reaches the relevant banking system.

See what happened to Pavel Durov recently...

"Laying their hands on you might be difficult if you stay on high sea": but it's probably a lot easier there than it would be if the offender were in another country. There would be no need to worry about extradition, for example. @JonCuster Germany has a coast guard, too, that would be happy to execute an arrest warrant for an IP pirate in international waters (perhaps even if the ship is registered in a different country).  Of course there is a cost/benefit analysis here; they surely have bigger fish to fry.  Then again, they might still be able to squeeze in some time for the small fry.

There are practical problems with this approach. Even if you succeed with getting a boat/platform in international waters, you will still be connected to the outside world via the Internet. The peering point will be a in country. The "copyright police" will put pressure on that point/country.
Pirate Radio worked because they were broadcasters that broadcast directly to radios in Britain. Pirate Bay worked because the local government didn't have laws that covered it (see other posts/sites if you want the full story).
If the country that contains your peering point successfully resists the "copyright police", it would be much easier to just setup a colocation facility in that country and skip the whole on a boat piece.
Once you get to large size, hiding your traffic flows becomes hard.
FYI, a lot of Kim Cartoon's servers were just normal colocation servers. He had front ends that hide the location of those servers (one was a Dutch company, the other was an American company based in VA).
As to the original question about getting into trouble. That all depends on you. If you are too small to care about, then no one is going to bother to find you. If you get large enough, the "Copyright Police" will start to pay attention. To get the Kim Cartoon treatment, you will have to very large, very loud, and make a public spectacle of yourself. You will also have to transit to/through a country that has a extradition treaty with the country of the "Copyright Police". It would take something like national secrets (like TS/SCI  nuclear/cryptographic stuff) before any military assault would come into play.

If we're focused only on arresting, there could be a loophole there.
The Principality of Sealand was an attempt at creating a "micronation" off the coast of the UK consisting of only a single World War II platform. It was originally used to broadcast pirate radio signals (as in not permitted by the UK). At the time, it was just outside the territory claimed by the UK (it now is considered UK territory). There's this interesting piece

In 1968, British workmen entered the claimed territorial waters of the Principality of Sealand to fix a buoy near the platform. Michael Bates (son of Patty Roy Bates) tried to scare the workmen off by firing warning shots from the platform. As Bates was a British subject at the time, he was called to court on firearm charges after the incident. However, the court said that the platform was outside of British waters and the case could not continue.

Countries have tightened some things up, but, in theory, you could use a non-ship structure and proclaim it as a "country". As long as it existed somewhere on the high seas in a semi-permanent way (i.e. maybe an oil rig moored to the floor) you would most likely be under maritime law. As such, it would make for some novel legal theories, the kind that might make any prosecutor think twice about charging you (plus you're in a place harder to send people to arrest you).
As to avoiding any repercussions, you'll still need Internet access, and it's possible (even probable) you would be cut off eventually, as the companies selling you access would be subject to the laws of the country they were based in (or possibly places they do business, like the European Union).

I recall reading something maybe a decade or two ago where someone was trying to set up a hosting service on a platform like this. The name Sea Land came to mind, but I can't recall whether it was the same platform. The idea was pretty much exactly what the OP describes.

Found it: https://www.wired.com/2000/07/haven-2/

@JimmyJames I knew someone proposed a tech-sector version but never got it running. Good find.

Weird that nothing about that is mentioned on the wikipedia page. I was always curious as to what happened with it.

I remember to read year ago that the loophole they used was closed so you no longer could do that with a new platform. I think it involved that the platform in international waters was considered under the sovereignty of the country of those that built it.

It probably bears remembering that such self-declared countries pretty much exist and continue to exist because nobody with an actual navy feels it's worth the hassle to deal with it. Once your micro-nation starts flouting actual laws that people care about (radio piracy is not generally one of those these days) on a regular basis, sooner or later someone is going to decide to do something about you and when that day comes you're going to be done.
